# Are there any libraries to work with HFile format in C++

Tags: c++, hbase, hfile

Searching for "hfile cpp" was quite an experience, that didn't end well. So I'm asking here if there are libraries that support HBase HFile manipulations (reading, writing, mapping to memory) in C++?

HFile is implementation of Google's SSTable format and is quite easy to use in Hadoop for example:
http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/io/hfile/HFile.html
http://cloudepr.blogspot.com/2009/09/hfile-block-indexed-file-format-to.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No at this time there are not any c++ libraries that I know of that target HBase's HFilev2.  HBase internals are currently pretty targeted to the JVM world.